What is a more formal way of saying "to the point of…"

I don't wanna make it worse to the point of destroying it.

Is this sentence grammatically correct despite the "wanna"? Is there a more formal equivalent of "to the point of"? I looked it up in a dictionary but it didn't show any synonyms.

to the point of  (idiom)
: to a particular state
The animals were hunted to the point of extinction.

Merriam-Webster

What do you think might be wrong with it? What makes you doubt that it is correct?

Nina! We meet again and again and again. Please register with EL&U, and you might be able to attract answers from our more senior users. Please stop creating new accounts for every new question.  You MUST add some detail, by now users will automatically close your questions because you are not making any effort to explain why you think a sentence is ungrammatical, you are only asking the community if a sentence is ungrammatical to fix it. That's called proofreading and is OFF-TOPIC.

I've edited the question but I see there's already one vote cast to close it. Maybe the edit will be enough to keep the question open for a day or more. It took me five minutes to show research and effort. You can do this. Stick to one account from now on. OK?

There's nothing particularly informal about it. The only 'synonym' is to say it in more words. "I don't want to make it so much worse that I end up destroying it", for example.

There are alternatives like simply using to, until, unto when to the point of is used with a noun following but they don't seem to work here.

seems redundant. Why include 'to the point of...' at all?

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+up+on+a+dictionary%2Cit+up+in+a+dictionary&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=read+it+in+the+paper%2Cread+it+on+the+paper&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Other alternative for "to the point  of" : "as far as to". Both expressions are quite formal.

You can start with want to instead of wanna. [grhh]

@ness the 'to' isn't optional / redundant in the M-W example. And I'd say the whole expression is valid in the original, though I'd add a dash.

It seems infelicitous to choose 'wanna' over 'want to' but simultaneously request a more formal variant of 'to the point of' (which is already more formal than informal).

"I don't wanna make it worse and risk destroying it." Not exactly the same, but perhaps similar enough. More formal sounding might be "I don't want to make it worse, lest I destroy it.

"To the point (of/where)" is not formal; this is confirmed in the main answer to this ELL question (which by the way seems to belong to the ELU). It is far from being informal, as well; for lack of a term as concerns language that fits no register, I'd say that this is "normal language".
As to the grammaticality of this sentence, no criticism can made except that it can be debated that there is the possible use of a comma after "worse", or even better, of a repetition of "worse" after a comma; this comma usage indicates an added precision or an afterthought. This use with and without the comma is found in the following page of results from Google Books: "worse(,) to the point of".

(The Tyranny of Numbers: Mismeasurement and Misrule -
Nick Eberstadt · 1995)  And now it was going to get worse, worse to the point of instability.

(The Road to Unafraid -
Jeff Struecker, ‎Dean Merrill · 2009)  As we ran the enemy fire grew worse, to the point that we had to take shelter for a moment

(The World According to Clarkson: The World According to ...
Jeremy Clarkson · 2005) What's more, the fruit they produced became worse and worse to the point where it could be used only in paraffin lamps.

(The Crucial Challenge for International Aid: Making the ... -
Mirek Karasek, ‎Jennifer P. Tanabe · 2014) The devil's spiral following causality starts with a simple economic crisis which gets worse to the point of society's revolting […].


As shown in the answer to the ELL question mentioned above, you can use "to the extent of", but the register remains the same.

I don't wanna make it worse to the extent of destroying it.

A distinction relative to this comma usage has to be made when the expressions "to the point of" and "to the extent of" are meant to indicate explicitly the degree of the worseness; the comma is then needed. Otherwise, it seems certain that the absence of comma is always associated with a statement specifically about the becoming worse and the degree reached rather than a statement of fact as concerns primarily the becoming worse.

— How much worse is it?
— It is worse to the point of our having to retreat on all fronts. (no comma can be used, it wouldn't make sense (probably obvious to most))

